# is Rails.cache purged between tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, rspec

We cache id/path mapping using `Rails.cache` in a Rails 3.2 app. On some machines it works OK, but on the others values are wrong. The cause is hard to track so I have some questions about the `Rails.cache` itself. Is it purged between tests? Is it possible that values cached in development mode is used in test mode? If it's not purged, how could I do it before running specs?

My cache store is configuration is:

```
#in: config/environments/development.rb
config.cache_store = :memory_store, {:size => 64.megabytes}

#in: config/environments/production.rb
# config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store
```

Comment: There is `test` environment for tests.

Comment: I know it, but I have just these two entires for `config.cache_store`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Add:

```
before(:all) do
  Rails.cache.clear
end
```

to have the cache cleared before each spec file is run.

Add:

```
before(:each) do
  Rails.cache.clear
end
```

to have the cache cleared before each spec.

You can put this inside `spec/spec_helper.rb` within the `RSpec.configure` block to have it applied globally (recommended over scattering it per spec file or case).

RSpec by default does not clear that cache automatically.

Comment: Why don't you just disable the cache on the tests?

Comment: @Francisco: because it doesn't prevent the cache to fetched. `config.action_controller.perform_caching = false` seems to just prevent *filling* the cache.

Comment: If we disable the cache on the tests, how we can test the cached responses itself? Cache validation, I believe, is one of the hardest part of programming, so if we have cached responses, we *should* test them.

Comment: You should be mocking the cache requests and responses. Using the actual cache needlessly couples your test code to implementation.

Comment: Just a side not, (for RSpec 3.8 at least), to put this in `spec/spec_helper.rb`, you'll need `config.before(:each) do blah end` instead of `before(:each) do blah end`

Answer (score 71):

A more efficient (and easier) method is to set the test environment's cache to use NullStore:

```
# config/environments/test.rb:
config.cache_store = :null_store
```

The NullStore ensures that nothing will ever be cached.

For instance in the code below, it will always fall through to the block and return the current time:

```
Rails.cache.fetch('time') { Time.now }
```

Also see the Rails Caching guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-nullstore

Comment: the only problem with this is that you can't test caching.