# Rails tutorial: undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm stuck (again!) at Chapter 9 (this time in section 9.2.2) of the Rails tutorial. I am getting

```
bundle exec rspec spec/
................................FFF........................

Failures:

1) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action 
 Failure/Error: before {sign_in user, no_capybara: true}
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `new_remember_token' for #<User:0x007f8181815448>
 # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:13:in `sign_in'
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:71:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The other 2 errors are of the same type.

Here is spec causing the errors:

```
    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
      let(:wrong_user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com")}
      before {sign_in user, no_capybara: true}

      describe "submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action" do
        before {get edit_user_path(wrong_user)}
        specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user'))}
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url)}
      end

      describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action" do
        before { patch user_path(wrong_user)}
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url)}
      end
    end
```

And here is the method (utilities.rb) the error message is complaining about:

```
def sign_in (user, options={})
  if options[:no_capybara]
    # Sign in when not using Capybara
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies[:remember_token]
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(remember_token))
  else
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
  end
end
```

The code for the model (User.rb) is here:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save { self.email = email.downcase}
before_create :create_remember_token
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}
has_secure_password

def User.new_remember_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def User.digest(token)
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end

private
  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
  end
end
```

I had previously trouble with the sign_in method but it [miraculously disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771899/failure-error-sign-in-user-undefined-method-sign-in). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the culprit for the erratic test results that I have been observing in this case and, quite likely, on previous occasions ([Failure/Error: sign_in user undefined method `sign_in'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771899/failure-error-sign-in-user-undefined-method-sign-in), [Rails named route not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520457/rails-named-route-not-recognized)). The problem seems to be that rails does not clear by default the cache between tests. Which is, actually, downright scary. It seems you cannot really trust the test results. I realised this by commenting out the method that rails was complaining about and re-running the test. The error persisted which meant one thing - rspec was simply working with some cached versions of the files and thus disregarding the changes which I am making. So even if the tests pass you can't be sure that they really do. This is really bizarre. After realising the problem with a bit of googling I found how to force rails to clean the cache - check jaustin's answer here: [is Rails.cache purged between tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309121/is-rails-cache-purged-between-tests)

Comment: Also forcing Guard polling can help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766511/tests-do-not-run-when-file-changes-with-guard-and-rspec-on-windows