# RSpec is caching my source code, I don't want it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I am using RSpec with RoR 4.1, if I run

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/citilink_request_spec.rb
```

or

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```

Then rspec will load the files correctly if it is the first execution, but at the second execution, it'll load the cached file. I can confirm this that the backtrace produced refer to the old point which I swapped with comment. It refers to a comment!

How can I disable this functionality, it shouldn't be de default setting IMHO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is Rails.cache purged between tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309121/is-rails-cache-purged-between-tests)

Comment: I tried that. no success. This is not the cache. But RSpec itself won't read the change in the source code

Answer (score 0):

It is not RSpec problem, but Sidekiq. Yah, I am using Sidekiq. And the Sidekiq part not loading again my code whenever it changes. So, I need to reload the Sidekiq and everything works as expected.

I should have mentioned that the code in question is working asynchronously in a worker executed by Sidekiq that is using Redis.